# Generate from WSDL is failing

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am trying to generate Apex class from WSDL file but I am getting below error:

Apex Generation Failed
Unable to find schema for element; {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string

Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

See below WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"    xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.example.com/1393912810519" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd2" xmlns:ns1="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.example.com/1393912810519">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:element name="VendorInterface">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_main">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="NAME1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="SORTL" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="BUS_TYPE" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ROUTE_CODE" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="VESTYR" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="VESTYB" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZTERM" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZWELS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="SPERM" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="REPRF" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="WAERS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZAHLS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="SPRAS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string"/>
                                  </xs:sequence>
                             </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_User">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="NAME1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="NAME2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                   <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_Tax">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="LAND1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STCEG" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ITTXAC" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STENR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ITRCVR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_Address">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="VASTYP" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="VABFRT" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STREET1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STREET2" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STREET3" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STREET4" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ORT01" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="LAND1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="WAERS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="SPRAS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="PSTLZ" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="SMTP_ADDR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="KOINH" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="INTAD" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_Paymen_Methods">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZWELS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="KOINH" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="REMARK" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="BANKA" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Vendor_ContactPerson">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="LIFNR" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="CNTTYP" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="NAMEV" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="NAME1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="CNSTYP" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="TEL_NUMBER" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="TEL_EXTENS" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="FAX_NUMBER" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="TEL_NUMBER2" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="TEL_EXTENS2" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="FAX_NUMBER2" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ZZ_ACTION" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd2" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:element name="VendorDetails" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:service name="VendorInterface">
        <wsdl:port name="VendorInfoEndpoint" binding="tns:VendorInfoEndpointBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8050/BusinessProcess/InterfaceImplementation/VendorInterface.serviceagent/VendorInfoEndpoint"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <wsdl:portType name="PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetVendorInfo">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetVendorInfo_Request"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetVendorInfo_Respone"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:GetVendorInfo_Fault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="VendorInfoEndpointBinding" type="tns:PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetVendorInfo">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/BusinessProcess/InterfaceImplementation/VendorInterface.serviceagent/VendorInfoEndpoint/GetVendorInfo"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Request"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Response"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault1"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:message name="GetVendorInfo_Request">
       <wsdl:part name="Request" element="ns0:VendorDetails"/>
    </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="GetVendorInfo_Respone">
        <wsdl:part name="Response" element="ns1:VendorInterface"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetVendorInfo_Fault">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Could you post the beginning of your WSDL please? It seems that you either must provide the related XML Schema or ignore any schema information when generating your classes.

Comment: I have added WSDL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for *GetVendorInfo_Request*. This has:

```
<xs:element name="VendorDetails" type="xs:string"/>
```

Wsdl2Apex doesn't support direct single-standard type requests or responses. Instead it would need to be nested in a complex type within a sequence. E.g.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd2" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/vendorInterface/SharedResource/Schema/Schema.xsd2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <!--
        This isn't supported by wsdl2Apex
        <xs:element name="VendorDetails" type="xs:string"/>
    -->

    <xs:element name="VendorDetails">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="inputParam" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

If you are unable to modify the WSDL then you can make the request directly using an HttpRequest by building up the required Soap XML payload yourself. I've been working with an intern on a tool to automate this. Unfortunately it doesn't directly support single standard type requests/responses yet either. If you are interested, see [WSDL Parser and Apex Generator](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx) (Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates this tool. It is free).

See also: [WSDL2APEX Parse error - Unable to find schema for element; {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xpcIAA)

Comment: @user3702503 Great. Convention on Stackoverflow is to use the green tick mark to indicate the accepted answer. This way others can find the answer. You can also vote answers up if you found them helpful.